# Import URL external bootstrap CSS file

Tags: css

It appears the css file is not importing , here's the code below. Is their a syntax error in

```
    <style type="text/css" id="sns_styles">
    @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');


    #myCarousel {
    margin-top: 40px;
   }

   .carousel-linked-nav,
   .item img {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;</style>
```

I think the error is in this line

```
    @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');
```

We have also tried adding 'http:' before the // in the link however the link still will not import the CSS file

Comment: In your link use `http://`, try: `@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');`

Comment: We tried using the http:// however it still doesn't seem to be importing correctly . Do you notice any other possible syntax errors ? @PrzemysławMelnarowicz

Comment: Is there any tests I can try to make certain my CSS file is importing correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'incorrectly'? It can be imported or not imported.

Comment: What I meant was it is not imported @PrzemslawMelnarowicz